# Add a history on calculator (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, calculator

I'm having a problem adding a history to calculator (`lblHistory` Label)
I want to store my previous inputs in the `lblHistory : UILabel`

but all it did is store the first number and its operation.

Is there any algorithm that you will store all previous inputs of your calculator?

This is my class MyCalculator.swift

**Class MyCalculator**

```
//
//  MyCalculator.swift
//  Calculator
//
//  Created by
//  abcdefgh
//

import Foundation

class MyCalculator
{
    var memory: Float = 0

    var percentnum: Float = 0

    var currentNum: Float = 0

    var result: Float = 0

    var operation: String = ""

    var isOperation: Bool = false

    var isRepeatOperation: Bool = false

    var isNum: Bool = false

    func operation (operation:String) -> Float
    {
        if operation == "+" {
            result = result + currentNum
        }
        else if operation == "-" {
            result = result - currentNum
        }
        else if operation == "*" {
            result = result * currentNum
        }
        else if operation == "/" {
            result = result / currentNum
        }
        return result
    }

    func percent(percentNum:Float) ->Float
    {
        let valpercent = percentNum * 0.01
        result = result * valpercent
        return result
    }

    func clearAll() {
        result = 0
        currentNum = 0
        isNum = false

    }

}
```

and this is the view controller of my calculator.

**View Controller**

```
/  ViewController.swift
//  Calculator
//
//  Created by 
//  abcdefgh
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Start Calculator


    //Label History: This is where the history is displayed
    @IBOutlet weak var lblHistory: UILabel!


    //Label Result: This is where the result is displayed
    @IBOutlet weak var lblResult: UILabel!


    //Initialization
    let calc = MyCalculator() //call the class MyCalculator

//Function for Number Inputs
@IBAction func btnNumInput(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let num = sender.currentTitle
    if calc.isNum == false
    {
        lblResult.text = num
        calc.isNum = true
    }
    else
    {
        lblResult.text = lblResult.text! + num!!
    }
    calc.isRepeatOperation = false
    lblResult.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
}

//Function for Operations
@IBAction func btnOperations(sender: AnyObject)
{
    calc.isNum = false
    if calc.isOperation && !calc.isRepeatOperation
    {
        calc.currentNum = Float(lblResult.text!)!
        if calc.operation == "+"
        {
            calc.result = calc.operation("+")
        }
        else if calc.operation == "-"
        {
            calc.result = calc.operation("-")
        }
        else if calc.operation == "*"
        {
            calc.result = calc.operation("*")
        }
        else if calc.operation == "/"
        {
            calc.result = calc.operation("/")
        }
        if calc.operation == "/" && calc.currentNum == 0
        {
            lblResult.text = "Cannot divide by zero"
            lblResult.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        }
        else
        {
            let stringresult = String(format:"%g" , calc.result)
            lblResult.text = "\(stringresult)"
            calc.isOperation = false
        }
    }
    else
    {
        calc.result = Float(lblResult.text!)!
    }

    let strresult = String(format:"%g", calc.result)
    calc.operation = sender.currentTitle!!
    lblHistory.text = strresult + calc.operation
    calc.isOperation = true
    calc.isRepeatOperation = true
}
```

From this code here:

```
let strresult = String(format:"%g", calc.result)
calc.operation = sender.currentTitle!!
lblHistory.text = strresult + calc.operation
```

this should store any input from the history label but it will only store the first input and its operator.

The result:

```
2+2 =4 //this is the input variables and operation
//the result is 4 and display on lblResult: UILabel
2+ // the "2+" is only stored in lblHistory: UILabel not the whole input itself
```

Comment: try to save inputs in an array of strings by `append`

Comment: I will append the result and currentNum in lblHistory? Like 

lblHistory.append(result, currentNum) ??

Comment: your `strresult` is `2+2=4`, but `lblHistory` = `2+`?

Comment: what if try this `lblHistory.text = strresult + String(calc.operation)`

Comment: yes @aaisataev I'll try that